# Display the Customer Details in one form after the customer login from previous page

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have an customer login page with customer ID and contact number. After they login, I need to display the customer details who login in previous page which are CustomerID, CustomerName, Gender, Phone, Email. I already have an database for  customer. Below is my code

`

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection
        Dim command As New SqlCommand
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-5E4GSPTU;Initial Catalog=VBN Assignment;Integrated Security=True"
        connection.Open()
        command.Connection = connection

        command.CommandText = "select * CustomerID, CustomerName, Gender, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress from CustomerRegistration"
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        If reader.HasRows Then
            reader.Read()
            TextBox1.Text = reader.Item("CustomerID")
            TextBox2.Text = reader.Item("CustomerName")
            ComboBox1.Text = reader.Item("Gender")
            TextBox3.Text = reader.Item("PhoneNumber")
            TextBox4.Text = reader.Item("EmailAddress")

            reader.Close()

        End If
        connection.Close()`
```

Comment: code does not seem complete?

Comment: Why aren't you using a Where clause to select the customer information for the logged in customer? Also, why do you select * followed by a column list? Also, what's working and what's not working?

Comment: You say "page" but you haven't specified the technology. Is this Web Forms or something else? More importantly, you haven't asked a question, i.e. you haven't told us what the actual issue is.

Comment: Think your issue might be you haven't filtered your query results in anyway, regardless of what ever customer logs in, it looks like you're going to see the first record in the CustomerRegistration table.  Think you're missing a where clause in your sql